# Error with installing Drush on via Ansible

Tags: vagrant

When installing Drush, with the following task

> action: command pear install drush/drush creates=/usr/bin/drush
>     tags: drush

I get the dollowing error:

> TASK: [Drush | Install drush] *************************************************  failed: [default] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["pear", "install", "drush/drush"], "delta": "0:00:01.318926", "end": "2014-02-14 09:25:46.666768",
>   "item": "", "rc": 255, "start": "2014-02-14 09:25:45.347842"} stderr:
>   PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in
>   /usr/share/php/PEAR/REST/13.php on line 80 PHP Warning:  Invalid
>   argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/REST/13.php on
>   line 84 PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use string offset as an array in
>   /usr/share/php/PEAR/REST/10.php on line 263 stdout:  Notice: Array to
>   string conversion in PEAR/REST/13.php on line 80
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/REST/13.php
>   on line 84
>
> FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

Comment: i'm getting the same error in a different situation. i installed ubuntu under virtual box, setup a lamp server, added pear and went to install drush and get the same error. Looking online I haven't found a solution yet. Suggestions I've seen are setting timezone in php.ini and upgrading pear. Neither helped.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this question while [researching the same error using the Vagrant LAMP Ansible Drupal (VLAD) project](https://bitbucket.org/philipnorton42/vlad/issue/5/errors-during-apache-drush-install-drush). I also happened to notice that the [PEAR installation instructions have just recently been removed (2 days ago) from Drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/445). It doesn't say explicitly that the pear channel has been disabled, but it does indicate that it might be a good time to consider switching to [Composer](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush#install---composer) or [manual](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush#install---manual) install of Drush.